# FBPlacePickerViewController not returning selection's correct location

Tags: facebook, ios6, location, mkmapview, viewcontroller

I'm using FBPlacePickerViewController on a project, and regardless of the selection I make on the picker, it always returns the same coordinates. I'm  using _placePicker.selection.location.latitude and _placePicker.selection.location.longitude and it always returns the userLocation (It doesn't matter the selection  made).

Answer (score 0):

Found a link that uses Google Maps to provide a workaround... It seems that there's a bug on Facebook Places SDK in that sense...

Anyways, here's a link to this "fix"

http://mithin.in/2009/06/22/using-iphone-sdk-mapkit-framework-a-tutorial